# Flink Twitter Streaming example not working for custom endpoint

Tags: twitter, apache-flink

I am extending flink connector on [github](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/) for getting twitter stream for  custom URL although I am able to get the Random tweets as given in the example code , but when I give a custom URL the tweets are not getting extracted (nothing gets printed on console and file).
I have written a customEndpoint as given below

```
public class CustomEndPoint implements EndpointInitializer, Serializable{
@Override
public StreamingEndpoint createEndpoint() {
    return new RawEndpoint("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23apple", "GET");     
}}
```

Below is how I am attching my custom end point to the TwitterSource class given in connector API

```
TwitterSource twitterSource = new TwitterSource(params.getProperties());
    twitterSource.setCustomEndpointInitializer(new CustomEndPoint());
        streamSource = env.addSource(twitterSource);
```

Also the same endpoint works when I modify the code of TwitterSource class directly(i.e hard-coding my endpoint to the field variable)  , but I don't want to do this as this is not the best way to use an API ,plus I lose the ability to give a different endpoint without code change

Comment: What is the url that you are able to get data from? My first question is if it is https as well.

Comment: yes it is https

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have to set the twitterSource host property. your host is not the default host used for Flink Twitter source client.

```
props.setProperty(TwitterSource.CLIENT_HOSTS,"https://api.twitter.com");
```

the default host that is used is "https://stream.twitter.com"
see the TwitterSource class, run method:

```
    client = new ClientBuilder()
        .name(properties.getProperty(CLIENT_NAME, "flink-twitter-source"))
        .hosts(properties.getProperty(CLIENT_HOSTS, Constants.STREAM_HOST))
        .endpoint(endpoint)
        .authentication(auth)
        .processor(new HosebirdMessageProcessor() {
```

...